# Emberjs 2.0+ update route model with new data from store (createRecord)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new to Ember, so my approach can be incorrect.
I am using latest Ember 2.9.1

My plan is to update route's model and cause all components to render newly added/saved item in a collection.

(I want to update my route's model (**userRoles** array) with a new record of **userRole** after I have call **save** (on **createRecord**)).

So far I have a **route** that has a **model** like this:

```
model(){
  // this is my "user.edit" route
  let user = this.modelFor('user');
  let newUserRole = this.get('store').createRecord('userRole');
  newUserRole.set('user_id', user.get('id'));

  return RSVP.hash({
    user: user,
    userRoles: store.query('userRole', { user_id: user.get('id') }),
    roles: store.findAll('role'),
    newUserRole: newUserRole
  });
}
```

I then have a controller and couple of components that modify newUserRole.
In a route I have an action for saving new user role:

```
actions: {
  saveNewUserRole: function () {
    let currentModel = this.modelFor('user.edit');
    currentModel.newUserRole.save().then(function (newUserRole) {
      currentModel.userRoles.addObject(newUserRole);
    });
  }
}
```

What's interesting is that a new item (newUserRole) gets added to a collection, but in console logging of model tells me that the new object is kind of different from other objects in the collection.
Looking through similar issues for ember I find that people use:
**_internalModel** or **toArray()**: [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3313) and [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3530) or services (?) for storing/updating data.

(also changed from using **pushObject** to **addObject** (v1.3+); plus observers listening for **userRoles** changes don't get triggered inside of components, or if I call **toArray()** I get 'Invalid value used as weak map key' error)

Question: What is the correct/Ember way to update my route's model with new item and cause to re-render my template. If I should use services for data, should service keep all items in a `toArray()` or POJOs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ember-data` will do most of the ugly relationship work for you automatically.

So for example you should never do something like this:

```
newUserRole.set('user_id', user.get('id'));
```

but always this:

```
newUserRole.set('user', user);
```

On a `.save()` `ember-data` is smart enough to save the id.

Also this looks a bit like you'r trying to load all `userRole`s for a given user:

```
store.query('userRole', { user_id: user.get('id') }),
```

You should only use `query` when necessary. To fetch a relationship just access the relationship:

```
user.get('roles'),
```

Assumed you have `roles: hasMany('userRole')` in your `models/user-role.js`.

Next with `currentModel.userRoles.addObject` you modify a result array of ember data. You should only do this if you want to change the relationship. `ember-data` will automatically keep your relationships in sync.
So after you've set the `user` on the `userRole`, the new role will be automatically in the live-array returned by `user.get('roles')`. So actually you should *never* modify the array returned by a `.query()`.

So basically this could be your `model` hook:

```
// this is my "user.edit" route
let user = this.modelFor('user');
let newUserRole = this.get('store').createRecord('userRole', {
  user
});

return RSVP.hash({
  user,
  userRoles: user.get('roles'),
  roles: store.findAll('role'),
  newUserRole,
});
```

And this could be your save-action:

```
actions: {
  saveNewUserRole: function () {
    let currentModel = this.modelFor('user.edit');
    currentModel.newUserRole.save();
  }
}
```

However if you only want to show the new role after you've saved it you probably should filter on `isNew=false` when viewing them. User a computer property like `userRolesFiltere: Ember.computed.filterBy('model.userRoles', 'isNew', false)` or a `{{#unless role.isNew}}` for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I am trying to setup page right now in this way. I however cannot make "user.get('roles')" call to actually make a request to server.

Comment: ...or rather do I have to return role ids as part of a call to user? I am using REST Adapter and if I don't return {roles: [role_ids]} as part of a user, ember won't make separate request(s) for the data

Comment: you have to [specify the link](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findBelongsTo).